# Installation of GPG alongside a running one: configure problem?

Tags: software-installation, osx, gpg

I already have a production version of GPG from a previous installation.

I would like to build and test the last version of GPG without interfering with the production one.
I am performing this test on MacOS X 10.10.3, but ideally this validation process should be independent of the OS.

I created a new repository directory different of the one where the running GPG is:

```
mkdir /local/gpg2
```

I downloaded the 4 required libraries and the `gnupg` archive:

```
libgpg-error-1.19
libgcrypt-1.6.3
libksba-1.3.3
libassuan-2.2.1
gnupg-2.0.27
```

I successfully built and installed `libgpg-error`:

```
cd libgpg-error-1.19
./configure --prefix=/local/gpg2
make
make install
```

and started to build `libgcrypt`:

```
cd ../libgcrypt-1.6.3
./configure --prefix=/local/gpg2
```

and this process fails with:

```
checking for gpg-error-config... no
checking for GPG Error - version >= 1.11... no
configure: error: libgpg-error is needed.
                See ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/libgpg-error/ .
```

I checked `config.log` where:

```
exec_prefix=NONE
prefix='/local/gpg2'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
```

and everything seems correct.

---

Where is this configuration problem coming from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're installing in non-standard locations, you'll need to tell each `configure` script where to find things. `./configure --help` should give an indication of the appropriate option; for `libgcrypt` you'd run

```
./configure --prefix=/local/gpg2 --with-libgpg-error-prefix=/local/gpg2
```

Except that because of a bug in `libgcrypt`'s `configure` script, only `--with-gpg-error-prefix` works, so you need to run

```
./configure --prefix=/local/gpg2 --with-gpg-error-prefix=/local/gpg2
```

The bug is already fixed in upstream's repository; it's [#1467](https://bugs.gnupg.org/gnupg/issue1467).