# Fail to Compile libgcrypt

Tags: linux, software-installation, gpg, configure

`libgpg-error-1.4.7` did install:

```
$ ls /opt/libgpg-error-1.47
bin  include  lib  share
```

And I tried to configure `libgcrypt-1.10.2`:
$ ./configure --with-libgpg-error-prefix=/opt/libgpg-error-1.47

`config.log` shows:

```
configure:15370: checking for gpg-error-config
configure:15401: result: /opt/libgpg-error-1.47/bin/gpg-error-config
configure:15412: checking for gpgrt-config
configure:15444: result: no
configure:15552: checking for GPG Error - version >= 1.27
configure:15600: result: no
configure:15610: error: libgpg-error is needed.
                See ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/libgpg-error/ .
```

I did notice another [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/207024/291139) mentioned using `--with-gpg-error-prefix` due to a bug but that bug has been fixed in `libgpg-error-1.4.7`

Any suggestion?